# How to sign in to webview on your app using firebase automatically?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, webview, firebase-authentication

I have an Android/iOS app that uses Firebase to sign in. I also want to integrate a webapp that uses the same authentication database using a webview. The webapp works on all 3 platforms, but requires the user to sign in/make an account first. I want to make it so that if the user is already signed in the app, he doesn't have to sign in a second time after opening the webview since he's already got an account with the app.